# How to create an action for Multiple dropdowns leading to a Sheet Selector?

Tags: tableau-api

I have 3 drop downs (parameters) on the main dashboard, When the values of all the 3 drop downs are been selected, I want the respective sheet to be displayed on the main dashboard like the sheet should be selected comparing the values of multiple drop downs accordingly

[Value + Sales Office + Tabular should result in the "Val_Sales Off_Tabular" sheet selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgDpi.png)

[Quantity + Sales Group + Visual should result in the "Qty_Sales Gr_Visual" Sheet selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8aM0.png)

Answer (score 1):

To control which sheets to display based on user dropdown selections create a calculated field with an IF, ELSEIF statement to assign a flag (0,1,2,etc.) to each of the combinations. Place all the sheets you want to show in one layout container and use the flags as filters on individual sheets to trigger them on and off. You can read more detailed guides on sheet swapping in Tableau on the Tableau  community forums or various data blogs.